# How could software developer spend free time while coding?

Tags: time-off

I'm a professional developer with about 20 hours of free time a week. I love coding, so I'd like to spend it on code, but I don't want to contribute to open source or find some spare money-job. Which options do I have?

Comment: Netflix and chill? Write poetry? Compose haiku?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for projects that will not leave you with any _responsibilities_ , so try Leetcode, Project Euler, [CodeGolf.se] ?

Comment: Work on an advanced degree or certification

Comment: Learn a new language / new tool, [at least one every year](https://pragprog.com/book/tpp20/the-pragmatic-programmer-20th-anniversary-edition).

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot to be said for *not* coding in your spare time as a professional, because that way leads to burnout. Do code-adjacent things like hacking robots, home automation, etc; or do non-technical things like volunteering for a charity, playing a sport, or building a deck. But if you code for 60+ hours a week, soon you’ll be looking for a way to code zero hours a week.

Answer (score 1):

- Do a hackathon
- Automate your home
- Teach a Udemy course
- Refresh your algorithms skills
- Found a startup
- Build one of my many ideas. I will happily provide you with some.
- Come up with ideas to add to this list